# How do I use the candy in Miitomo?

Tags: miitomo

So, I've gotten the candy from the drop game, and I know what it does (allows you to view previous answers by friends). I plan on using it to see more of my friends questions (right now I can only see 2 from each friend) but I can't figure out how to use it. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 10):

There is two ways to use it.

- If you're talking to a friend's Mii in his room. After he gave you three answers, he will ask you one candy to give another answer. You can simply give him when he asks for it.

[image]

- If you're on the "Unheard" screen in the Mii's room. As you are able to select the question, the Mii will ask you 2 candies. You can then just select the question you want and use your two candies by clicking the "Get an answer" button.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll need to visit a friend of yours.  Next, you'll want to pull up Answers, if it isn't already.  There will be two tabs in the Answers section on the screen, select Unheard.  From there, you can spend 2 Candies to hear/see the answer of a question of your choice.